# ¿Cómo hago para que "whoami" con root dé el nombre del usuario?

Tags: bash, root

Cuando uso una `whoami` para almacenar el usuario en una variable en bash si ese script se ejecuta con sudo se almacena el usuario root.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que siga almacenándose el usuario normal?

```
usuario=$(whoami)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes probar esto:

`usuario=${SUDO_USER:-$USER}`

Con esto, si estás ejecutando el script con `sudo`, tomará el valor de la variable `SUDO_USER`. Y en el caso de que lo ejecutes con tu usuario, tomará el valor de `$USER` (valor por defecto si `SUDO_USER` está vacío)

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Con `whoami` solo conseguirás el usuario que ejecuta el script. Tal como pone en su [página man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whoami.1.html):

> print effective userid

Pero he encontrado estas otras opciones válidas para ello usando la variable `$SUDO_USER` o bien el comando `who`, o bien `logname`:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

opcion1=$SUDO_USER
echo "opcion1="$opcion1

opcion2=`who | awk '{print $1}'`
echo "opcion2="$opcion2

opcion3=`who | cut -d' ' -f1`
echo "opcion3="$opcion3

opcion4=`who | sed -n 's/^\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'`
echo "opcion4="$opcion4

opcion5=`logname`
echo "opcion5="$opcion5
```

Prueba la que más te convenga según tengas instalado el `awk` o el `sed` o ninguno de los dos.